# Hide a div when magnific popup opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i use magnific pop up for an image gallery and i want to hide a div when the image zoom in and show it again when the image zoom out. This is my code :

```
 $('.gallery-item').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        gallery:{
          enabled:true
        },
        mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom', // this class is for CSS animation below

        zoom: {
        enabled: true, // By default it's false, so don't forget to enable it

        duration: 300, // duration of the effect, in milliseconds
        easing: 'ease-in-out',


         // CSS transition easing function

        // The "opener" function should return the element from which popup will be zoomed in
        // and to which popup will be scaled down
        // By defailt it looks for an image tag:
        opener: function(openerElement) {
          // openerElement is the element on which popup was initialized, in this case its <a> tag
         // you don't need to add "opener" option if this code matches your needs, it's defailt one.
         return openerElement.is('img') ? openerElement : openerElement.find('img');
       }
      }

});
```

Where should i put the the hide() and show() functions so they will be triggered same time with the magnific popup.

Comment: There is no hidden value for display in css. Please post your completed code or provide a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `$( ".main" ).hide();` in your open function.

Comment: the open close function dont work actually,i edited the code again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use css for that, jQuery has built in functions for showing and hiding elements.

```
open: function(){
  $(".main").hide();
},
  close: function(){
  $(".hidden-div").show();
}
```

Comment: this function don't work, i edit the description. Can you help me how can i do this thing work?

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a way to capture a zoom event.